# How to add the value in the dropdown as the last element?

Tags: html, select

I have a select element and its option as:

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

At run time some more values will come which will be shown as:

> Value 1, Hi, Bye

Now, what I want is that `Value 1` should come at the last if more values are coming at runtime. It should be done through HTML.

Do we have something like last value should be ".." in HTML?

Comment: What I want is a Porsche. You can't always get what you want just by asking for it...

Comment: Actually I tried searching for this but found link use of last-child in javascript but actually wanted to change in HTML only

Answer (score 0):

append Value 1 also runtime after all your values appdend in the dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose u have a question. But I don't see one.
For info about select, look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Edit:
I see that the question is changed. It is not possible to give a order for the Select statement. The only thing u can do is to change the order with javascript or php or whatever or manually.

Comment: Thanks for the link but only options are populated here. I need to put the value at the last of dropdown if some more values are coming at run time, through HTML. I got add() method but it is used in javascript